# Native dependencies not copied when indirectly referenced as a NuGet dependency

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget, native

I have an internal NuGet package that is dependent on another NuGet package that has native dependencies. In a .NET SDK console application I am referencing the internal NuGet package and indirectly referencing the other NuGet package that has the native dependencies.

When the NuGet package with native dependencies is referenced indirectly, the native dependencies are not copied properly to the bin directory.

If the NuGet package with native dependencies is installed directly as a direct dependency, then the native dependencies are copied over properly.

Will this always be the case, and we just need to add the NuGet package with native dependencies as a direct dependency to any project using our internal NuGet package? Or is there something that could be added to our internal NuGet package or something that could be added to the other NuGet package to get native dependencies to copy correctly when referenced indirectly?

Our internal NuGet package is build with `dotnet pack` using info from the csproj file to create the NuGet package.

Comment: Have a look at [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets), by default `PrivateAssets` is being set to `contentfiles;analyzers;build`, and parent project won't flow your custom target from `build` folder

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I was able to resolve my problem with information from that link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using the package reference modifiers described here [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets)

The default for `PrivateAssets` is to prevent contentfiles, analyzers, and build files from propagating to referencing projects. The native files were in the build folder of the NuGet package that I was referencing along with the .targets file to define what files needed to be copied. Changing `PrivateAssets` to only exclude contentfiles and analyzers fixed the problem of downstream projects not copying the native files properly.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="SomeLibraryWithNativeDependenciesInTheBuildFolder" Version="1.2.3">
  <PrivateAssets>contentfiles,analyzers</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```